# Manually updating Wordpress files

Tags: updates

Hi currently have wordpress **4.7** installed .  I want to upgrade it **4.7.3** . But wthe problem is that in many of wordpress root folder we have other custom folder and files , that We don't want to lose .

I see the release archive https://codex.wordpress.org/Version_4.7.3 .
 It showed the List of Files Revised . So what we are planing to do is **take each file individually and replace it with the new released file** , for example take *old  wp-admin/js/common.js* and **replace** it with *new wp-admin/js/common.js* . Is it possible ? .Is it a good method to update ?  If i update this way my website is 100% update to new version .

Answer (score 0):

Updating WordPress through the dashboard will only affect WordPress files.  No other files will be touched.  Do the updates in the admin dashboard.   Only files that need to be updated will be updated.  Even WordPress files that don't need updating will not be touched.

Comment: Thank you . This is good information . But could you please tell the way we are palnning have any disadvantage ? .

Comment: Because 1 you may miss a file and 2 if this were a process you usually use you could miss necessary database updates.

Comment: @rudtek You can automate the file by file update though, e.g. using find, and database updates will be applied when you next start the site - they're not part of the core update process. But I agree the automatic process is good enough.

Comment: Could you please check this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/263072/wordpress-post-filter-using-ajax

Comment: what did you want me to check?  Did this question not get solved?